# Equinumerosity between equivalence classes set and power set

Tags: equivalence-relations

I´m currently working on the following problem:

"Let $\xi$ = $\{ $ $\bot$  $\mid $$\bot$ is a equivalence relation over  $\mathbb{N} $$\} $

Show that $\xi$ and $2^\mathbb{N} $ (power set) are equinumerous."

Edit: After some research, I found that I need to proof that $2^\mathbb{N} $ is equinumerous with  $2^\mathbb{NxN} $, because $\xi $ $\space{ }$  $\subseteq$ $\space{ }$$2^\mathbb{NxN} $. Any ideas?

Comment: It may be easier to construct injections in each direction rather than trying to come up with a bijection explicitly.

Comment: $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ are equinumerous.

Comment: To prove $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb {N \times N}$ are equinumerous, you can look at [pairing functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function) or the [countability of the rationals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set)

Answer (score 1):

To inject $2^{\Bbb N}$ into $\xi$ (to within a factor $2$, but that is finite and can be patched up), given a subset you have an equivalence relation by the partition that subset/its complement.

To show that $|\xi| \le |\Bbb R|$, if $A_i$ is an element of the partition, associate with it the real number $a_i=\sum_{j \in A_i}3^{-j}$.  Now associate the whole partition with the real $\sum_{i=1}^{|A|} a_i4^{-i}$